# How to parse a Sharepoint Date from Hex to a java.util.Date

Tags: java, sharepoint, date, groovy

I'm trying to parse a Date from a MS Sharepoint into a java.util.Date.
The Details:
I query a Sharepoint from a Grails webapp via the SOAP GetListItems method.
In the Sharepoint list, the date is displayed correctly, here 09/11/2009 but in the SOAP response, I get

```
0x01ca60cf|0x94894000
```

Further, this only happens with docx, pptx, etc. file types.
So, does anyone know how to convert this into a java.util.Date?
I already tried converting the two hex values to a Long or to bytes and shifting them around, but all algorithms I googled only work for the supplied sample hex values.

**[Edit]** For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389046/what-is-the-specification-of-hexadecimal-date-format-in-sql-server) SO solution (converted to Java) didn't work for my values.

Comment: In the schema for the response what is the Data Type of the date ? Do you know what Format the Date is stored in in Sharepoint ?

Comment: In Sharepoint, the data type is 'Date and Time', and in another lib it is just 'Date'; I can't exactly say what the data type in the response is, it is a part of the ows_MetaInfo attribute string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of educated trial and error, I ended up with this:

```
def date = "0x01ca60cf|0x94894000"

// Parse our hex numbers into a single number
def nums = Long.parseLong( date.split( /\|/ ).collect { it.replace( '0x', '' ) }.join( '' ), 16 ) / 10000
// MS calendar goes from 1600...  Java's goes from 1970, so we need to make up the difference
nums += Calendar.instance.updated( year:1601, month:0, date:1 ).time.time

println "Converted date is ${new Date( nums as Long )}"
```

You would probably want to do much more testing to make sure it isn't just a fluke I get the right date on this occasion...

Do you have more values to test it on?

**EDIT**...

Ahhh...the only bit I wasn't sure about was why I needed to do `/ 10000`, but the [documentation for ticks in the DateTime object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) shows that:

> A single tick represents one hundred
>   nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a
>   second. There are 10,000 ticks in a
>   millisecond.

Which explains it :-)

Comment: It works! I tested it on several values. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool :-)  The only bit I can't explain is the `/ 10000`...but if it works, it works ;-)

Comment: Solved the `/ 10000` quandry, and put why in the answer